# When 2 lines on ASP:Chart have the same values, is there a way to see both lines?

Tags: asp.net, line, aspchart

I have an ASP:Chart that has 2 lines.

1. Light Green for average
2. Dark Green for highest value

Some months, there is just one data point, so the high = average. When this happens on the chart, you can only see one line color. Is there a trick to get both lines to display squeezed together? I'd like to see the light green and dark green touching each other in these cases.